# How to raise events of backgroundworker

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++

I am using VS2010, C++/CLR WindowsFormsApplication. I want to raise `RunWorkerComplete` event using `BackGroundWorker->OnRunWorkerComple` method

```
backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync();
while (progressBar1->Value != progressBar1->Maximum)
{
    progressBar1->Value = ParentForm1->ImportedData[ComboBoxSelectedItemID]->ProgressStatus; 
}
```

The thing is that in `backgroundworker1` I start some time-consuming operation. 
And while BGW `isBusy` progressbar is cheking value of `int` Variable `ProgressStatus`.
But the problem is that `RunWorkerCompleted` doesn't raise.
So how can I raise it in `DoWork`?

```
private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) 
{
    MyClassObject->TimeConsumingOperation();
    //how to raise RunWorkerCompleted here??? 
}
```

Comment: This is called "deadlock".  The RunWorkerCompleted event handler cannot be called until the UI thread goes idle.  It isn't idle, it is stuck in that loop you wrote.  Burning 100% core no less.  The point of using BGW is to not get your UI thread code stuck in a loop and stop responding to paint and input request.  You will have to remove that loop, use the ProgressChanged event instead.

Comment: So I cant raise RunWorkerComple event inside DoWork ???
my ScaleArray function doesn't return any value, so I cant use report progress for BWG1.